# What is this component that looks like a resistor?

Tags: identification, components

I'm attempting to repair the power amplifier PCB for a Laney Session 40 Reverb guitar amplifier. I think this component is a resistor, but I have never seen one like this before.

[image]

Comment: Probably because it looks more like a diode.

Comment: Looks like a diode with somewhat displaced polarity mark. A bigger picture with surrounding elements could help.

Comment: Could also be a zero ohm jumper but I agree a better picture with more surrounding detail would help.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is a diode. When I read the colors from right to left I see yellow, brown, yellow, gray = 4148.

So this could be a 1N4148.

Answer (score -4):

Yes it looks like it is a resistor.

You can obtain its value through with this image:
https://www.jameco.com/Jameco/workshop/CircuitNotes/circuit_notes_resistors-fig1.jpg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No, it doesn't.